# Can I set two Chrome Gmail shortcuts to open different accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, shortcuts

I've just integrating my POP3 email for my business into a Gmail account. I like using Chrome's application shortcuts to open Gmail and Google Reader.

Thing is, I also have a personal Gmail address that I often check "at work", and my Reader subscriptions are also in my personal account.

Problem is, Chrome will only keep me logged in to one account at a time.I don't want to keep logging out of one and into another account.

Can I set one shortcut to open one account, and another to use a different account?

Answer (score 1):

You can point each Gmail app instance shortcut to a different user data directory. This is like having multiple profiles on FireFox.  The shortcut will need to take an extra parameter `--user-data-dir=.path/to/dir`. Looking at [the documentation](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) you can see where the default directory would be for you, and in the case of linux, you could:

```
cp -R ~/.config/google-chrome/Default ~/.config/google-chrome/personal-gmail
chrome --user-data-dir=$HOME/.config/google-chrome/personal-gmail ...
```